# cannot find custom function in my python module

Tags: python

I put several custom functions in a python script, and create `__init__.py` at the same directory.
I move this directory to python package directory, and it and the functions contained can be loaded successfully.

But, when I try to add a new function to the script, I reload the module but I cannot find the function. I see that function just stays inside the scripts normally. But python seems ignore this function.

I have tried to recompile this module, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that you are importing the right version of your module? Try `import your_module; print(your_module.__file__)`

Comment: How are you reloading the module?

Comment: I add some functions to mymodule.py in directory "pkg" in the python package directory, then I load it through "Import pkg.mymodule as mymodule ", and call the function through "mymodule.function1(...)". It works. But I add some new functions to mymodule.py, and reload it still through "Import pkg.mymodule as mymodule ", the new functions are not found. But I tried rename the mymodule.py to another name and it works.

Comment: @Tianlang: It's unclear from your response, but reloading a module by importing it again in the same Python session does not really reload it — because Python caches loaded modules in `sys.modules` and just reuses the previously loaded module object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and ended up having to rename my *.py file to get it running, but what intrigued me was that even after I renamed it, I was still able to import the old file. Then I realized that I had placed the same name *.py file in the Anaconda installation directory so that I could import it directly. So after I went back to the Anaconda installation directory and deleted the old *.py file with the same name, my program was able to import the *.py file normally